# Converting "from ... in " iteration in C# to C++ (Qt)

Tags: c#, c++, qt, loops

I have one fragment written in C# , and now I want convert it to Qt environment. The C# code is the following:

```
double xSum = (from p in this select p.X).Sum();
double ySum = (from p in this select p.Y).Sum();
```

Note: in c# version variable p is NOT predefined.

I tried converting it with foreach, while loops but got a lot of errors. Could you help me doing it?

here is my qt version, which does not work

```
QPointF p;
double xSum = 0;
double ySum = 0;
foreach(p, this)
{
   xSum = xSum + p.rx();
   ySum = ySum + p.ry();
}
```

The main question: what is the equivalent of 'from in' in Qt?

Comment: Please show your C++ code (along with types), very unclear what you have problem with as basic `for` and `+=` should be enough...

Comment: Please see the post edited.

Comment: Instead of adding answer to post you could answer it yourself and accept it.

Comment: I am new here, and didn't know that it is allowed. But thanks for information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]: I have solved it by myself as follows :

```
QPointF p;
double xSum = 0;
double ySum = 0;
for(QVector::iterator it=this->begin(); it!=this->end(); it++)
{
    xSum = xSum + it->rx();
    ySum = ySum + it->ry();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ uses lambda's for this:

```
double xSum = std::accumulate(begin(), end(), 0.0,
  [](double d, QPointF p) { return d + p.rx(); } );
double ySum = std::accumulate(begin(), end(), 0.0,
  [](double d, QPointF p) { return d + p.ry(); } );
```

Alternatively:

```
 double xSum = 0;
 std::for_each(begin, end, [&](QPointF p) { xSum += p.rx(); });
```

The most straightforward conversion would be

```
 double xSum = 0;
 for (auto p : *this) { 
   xSum += p.rx(); 
 }
```